# Is there a way in linux to increase the MTU size of a Broadcast interface on linux to be able to send bigger UDP packets?

Tags: linux, udp, broadcast

I am broadcasting UDP packets on a `Bcast:192.168.1.255` of a `wlan0` interface on linux. Its working well and I am receiving an UDP client written on another machine. I learnt that I cannot send a UDP packet bigger than the MTU size stated on that particular interface.

The broadcast interface's MTU size states *1500*. So, tests indicate like I cannot send a UDP bigger than 1500 bytes? I can send smaller UDP packets which I confirmed works.

**Question**
Is there a way in linux to increase the MTU size of a Bcast interface on linux? What are the drawbacks if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ip link` command is a key; can it change MTU for a wlan connection?

Either way : `ip link set wlan0 mtu 4000`

But do the AP supports sk jumbo frames or can it be configured to do that?

Linux uses MTU discovery when sending UDP so outbound and outsize UDP packets can be rejected by the system (EMSGSIZE error.)
MTU Path discovery can be disabled but still the network equipment will drop outsize datagrams (and it won't fragment them.)

UDP = User Datagram Protocol (so as a default it should reject oversize packets , one datagram = one (ethernet) frame)

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. `ip link set wlan0 mtu 2304` works. But looks like on my embedded linux device, I cannot go above `2304`. Is 2304 the hard limit?

Comment: That could be on your device or the access point.It works in a wired environement (caveeat emptor i have only tested it using esxi virtual switches) using the default intel e1000g device. In that case around 9kB packets was possible (again THIS is jumbo frames  so...) This is i would say very much hw dependent !!